# passing argument 1 of 'functionName' from incopatible pointer type

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a function that changes my 2d array and saves changes to it

The code is working but warnings about pointers appear, and I don't know how to bypass it with my yet basic knowledge of C language

```
#include <stdio.h>
int size = 0;

void functionName(char (*tab)[size][size]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            (*tab)[i][j] = (*tab)[i][j]-'0';
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    scanf("%d", &size);
    char tab[size][size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            scanf("%c", &tab[i][j]);
        }
    }
    functionName(tab);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because `char tab[][]` decays to a `char (*)[]` when passed as an argument, which doesn't match the type `functionName` expects. To resolve the inconsistency, either:

- pass `tab` as a `char (*)[][]` by calling `functionName(&tab)` instead;
- or, change the argument type of `functionName` to `void functionName(char tab[size][size])`, and fix the code inside the function to use `tab[i][j]` instead of `(*tab)[i][j]`.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is as answered by [dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64841374/2410359)

C99 with variable length arrays or select later version of C, use:

```
void functionName(int size, char tab[size][size]) {
  ...
}
```

and call with

```
functionName(size, tab);
```

---

Also suspect OP's `scanf("%c", &tab[i][j]);` should change to `scanf(" %c", &tab[i][j]);`  (Add space)